# Another try. List don't remove properly

Tags: unity, c#

I hve that script:

```
public void ActivateCard(Card card)
        {
            Debug.Log("Activating card: " + card.CardsData);
            if (card.CardsData.creatureName != string.Empty)
                Summon(card);
            else
                CastSpell(card);

            if (_hand.Cards.Contains(card))
            {
                _hand.Cards.Remove(card);
                Debug.Log("Card " + card.CardsData.cardName + " deleted");
                Debug.Log("now we have(cards): " + _hand.Cards.Count);
            }
                

            _hand.TakingCards(0);
        }
```

And I expect that card will be removed from the list. But it allways remove only FIRST element in there. Here's what I have(card can't be the same in one list):
[image]

ADDICTION:

It's not a full code, but it's all we need I think.
Here's how this method calls:
-I-

```
public class InputClass
{
  void Update
  {
    if (targetSet)
     {
         if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                    Cancel(true);
     }
  }

  void Cancel(bool isDone){ _actCard.Cancel(isDone); }
}
```

-II-

```
class ActCard
{
  public void Cancel(bool isDone)
  {
    if (isDone)
     {
        _activator.ActivateCard(_card);
     }
  }
}
```

-III-

```
class CardActivator
{
  public void ActivateCard(Card card)
        {
            Debug.Log("Activating card: " + card.CardsData);
            if (card.CardsData.creatureName != string.Empty)
                Summon(card);
            else
                CastSpell(card);

            if (_hand.Cards.Contains(card))
            {
                _hand.Cards.Remove(card);
                Debug.Log("Card " + card.CardsData.cardName + " deleted");
                Debug.Log("now we have(cards): " + _hand.Cards.Count);
            }
        }
}
```

-IV-

````
public class Hand
{
  List<Card> _hand = new List<Card>();
  
  public List<Card> Cards
        {
            get { return _hand; }
            set { _hand = value; }
        }
}
```
````

Comment: Did you implement IEquatable or override Equals() and GetHashCode() in your Card class?

Comment: @Zibelas no... What exactly should I do?

Comment: Basically contains does not know how to identify the correct card in your list since you didn't implement those. You can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629124/contains-on-a-list-of-custom-class-objects Your equals should return something that is unique for all your cards, like an id, name or a combination.

Comment: @Zibelas oh! I see! Even if I have `card.CardsData.cardsName` it doesn't counts, right?

Comment: You can use that for your id, but the List contains function does not know you want this or that it can use this as identifier. It should be as simple as override the Equals in your Card class and just return the cardsName. Another thing, if you have twice the same card, player uses the second, would it matter if the first gets remove?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. Just for now I have not so many cards, so they casn't be the same. Just now. But maybe...if it's a game...maybe it IS matter...I didn't really think about it

Comment: Rather think about it early than late. Imagine you have a bord with tab abilities that you can use each round. If you have three times the same card, click on the second and the first one gets turned/ used, what would happen now if you click on the third? Is your logic resolver checking the first and sees it can't use the card? Or does it check the third but applies resolves to the first?

Comment: Thank you m8 :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117614/discussion-between-dead-lord-and-zibelas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically contains does not know how to identify the correct card in your list since you didn't implement those. You can take a look at this stackoverflow.com/questions/2629124/… Your equals should return something that is unique for all your cards, like an id, name or a combination.